# SSL in HazelCast

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, hazelcast

I am trying to evaluate Hazel Cast for a distributed lock and a Session management within our web application. Our PCI environment needs all the components to run on Secure Port.I recently found that the Hazelcast needs Enterprise version to enable SSL,In our case it might not be cost effective as the only enterprise feature i use will be SSL.

So the question is

Can i create a small spring war file that brings up hazelcast,deploy it on tomcat and further enable SSL on tomcat?.

Does this approach has any pitfalls?.

Please let me know the thoughts. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so, but the ports opened by Hazelcast would not run over the connection opened by Tomcat. Hazelcast opens its own connections which are independent of the http connectors of Tomcat.
The protocol used by Hazelcast is not http based, it supports the memcache ascii protocol.

Even the new binary client protocol designed for Hazelcast does not change this: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/protocol/1.0-developer-preview/client-protocol.html

So if you need secure connections you either have to buy the enterprise edition or secure those connections in the network layer (Vpn, tunnels, ...) which might be difficult depending on if you use multicast and ephemeral ports or not.

Comment: I switched to Apache Ignite.. It is free and does almost everything that hazelcast does.